# How to returns empty string instead of null in jbuilder views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I have simple jbuilder view

```
json.id pharmaceutic.id
json.name pharmaceutic.name
json.dosage pharmaceutic.dosage.name
```

When `pharmaceutic.dosage => nil`

My rendered json looks like below:

```
{"id":1,"name":"HerzASS ratiopharm","dosage":null}
```

I would like set up for all jBuilder views that when some attribute is `nil` it should be rendered as empty string.

```
{"id":1,"name":"HerzASS ratiopharm","dosage":""}
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Maybe by doing this? `json.dosage pharmaceutic.dosage.name || ""` with this operand if `dosage.name` is `nil` it will use the empty string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nil.to_s #=> ""` so, you can simply add `.to_s`

```
json.id pharmaceutic.id
json.name pharmaceutic.name.to_s
json.dosage pharmaceutic.dosage.name.to_s
```

Comment: This is good solution but I am looking an answer where i don't need to ad ``to_s`` for all my 500 attributes.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on the accepted answer, here's a simple proxy class to do just that:

```
class Proxy

  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def method_missing method, *args, &block
    if @object.respond_to? method
      @object.send(method, *args, &block).to_s
    else
      super method, *args, &block
    end
  end

  def respond_to? method, private = false
    super(method, private) || @object.respond_to?(method, private)
  end

end

class Roko < Struct.new(:a, :b, :c)
end

# instantiate the proxy instance by giving it the reference to the object in which you don't want nils
roko = Proxy.new(Roko.new)

puts roko.a.class # returns String even though :a is uninitialized
puts roko.a       # returns blank
```

Answer (score 0):

> json.dosage pharmaceutic.dosage.name.to_s

This will not work if pharmaceutic is nil. you can simply do

```
json.dosage pharmaceutic.dosage.name unless pharmaceutic.dosage.nil?
```